# get record from a specific date

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i'm currently doing a payroll. I already managed to compute the hours of employees with the time-in and time-out on the same date. Here's a sample table of the records i am fetching. My problem is, i can't figure out what condition to use if the employee works in a 10pm-6am shift or similar shift that requires them to work until the next day. Im using distinct in my query because the data provided by the hr contains many duplicate entries.

```
----------------------------------------------------
| empID     |   Date     |    Type    |   RecTime  |
----------------------------------------------------
|   1      | 2012-11-01  | 1-TIME IN  |    21:45   |
|   1      | 2012-11-02  | 1-TIME OUT |    06:05   |
|   1      | 2012-11-02  | 1-TIME IN  |    21:33   |
|   1      | 2012-11-03  | 1-TIME OUT |    06:08   |
|   1      | 2012-11-04  | 1-TIME IN  |    11:49   |
|   1      | 2012-11-04  | 1-TIME OUT |    21:39   |
|   1      | 2012-11-05  | 1-TIME IN  |    14:25   |
|   1      | 2012-11-05  | 1-TIME OUT |    20:07   |
----------------------------------------------------
```

Here is my PHP code:

```
<?php

$c = 1;
$query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT EmpID, Date, Type from paymaster2c.tx_tito_pm ORDER BY EmpID, Date");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
$EID = $row['EmpID'];
$D = $row['Date'];
$T = $row['Type'];

$RTi = 'no time in';
$RTo = 'no time out';
$RBo = 'no break out';
$RBi = 'no break in';

$query1 = mysql_query("SELECT RecTime from tx_tito_pm WHERE Date='$D' AND EmpID='$EID' AND Type='1-TIME IN' LIMIT 1");
while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($query1)){
$RTi = date('H:i:s',strtotime($row1['RecTime']));

    if (date('H:i:s',strtotime('$RTi')) > date('H:i:s',strtotime('03:00 PM')) && date('H:i:s',strtotime('$RTi')) <= date('H:i:s',strtotime('11:59 PM'))) {
    $date = new DateTime('$D');
        $date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
        $NewDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');

        //$NewD = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('$D + 1day'));
        $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT RecTime from tx_tito_pm WHERE Date='$date' AND EmpID='$EID' AND Type='4-TIME OUT' LIMIT 1");
            while ($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3)){
                $RTo = date('H:i:s',strtotime($row3['RecTime']));

                $RTii = date('H:i:s',strtotime('23:59:00')) - date('H:i:s',strtotime($RTi));

            $start_date = new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime('23:59:00')));
            $since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime('$RTi'))));
            $start_date1 = new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime('00:00:00')));
            $since_start1 = $start_date1->diff(new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime('$RTo'))));

            $M1 = $since_start1->i ;
            $H1 = $since_start1->h ;
            $M = $since_start->i ;
            $H = $since_start->h ;
            $a = $H + $H1;
            $b = $M + $M1;


            $RTD = $RTo-$RTi;

            echo "#" .$c. "   ". $EID . " == " . $D . " == " . date('D', strtotime($D)) ." == " . $T ." ==>>" .$RTo. "-". $RTi. "==" .$RTD. "//" .$a. "hrs and " .$b. "minutes. <br /> \n";
            $c++;
            }

    }
    else {

    $query2 = mysql_query("SELECT RecTime from tx_tito_pm WHERE Date='$D' AND EmpID='$EID' AND Type='4-TIME OUT' LIMIT 1");
        while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2)){
        $RTo = date('H:i:s',strtotime($row2['RecTime']));

            $start_date = new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime($RTo)));
            $since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime(date('H:i:s',strtotime($RTi))));

            $M = $since_start->i ;
            $H = $since_start->h ;


            $RTD = $RTo-$RTi;

            echo "#" .$c. "   ". $EID . " == " . $D . " == " . date('D', strtotime($D)) ." == " . $T ." ==>>" .$RTo. "-". $RTi. "==" .$RTD. "//" .$H. "hrs and " .$M. "minutes. <br /> \n";
            $c++;

        }
    }
}


}
echo $c;
?>
```

hopefully someone can help me with this. thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Please don't use `mysql_*`, it's outdated and unsecure. Read about PDO and MySQLi.

Comment: you need to maintain extra information at table level. Need to maintain the shift in which each employee is working, start and end timing for each shift. You should not use DISTINCT because, employee might do entry and exit multiple times in a shift. With this info, you should be able to meet the requirement.

Comment: @FranciscoPresencia, i'm still trying to learn PDO and MySQLi at the moment. still learning, but thanks though.:)

Comment: @rags, actually they do have a starting and ending time for the shift. but it varies depending on the shift assigned to them for that day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to ultimately develop new or additional tables to help you with this problem (if you want to pursue a MySQL centric solution).  Below is a brute force query that probably needs to be optimized / personalized to include:

- Make sure you have an index on the required fields
- (IMHO) Create SQL Views to encapsulate those derived tables (i.e., the repeating Select's within parenthesis)
- I did not know your field types.  So I assumed the time was a character field.  This may need to change
- You may want to possible run a variation of this query to populate a temporary table or work table.  The self-join to determine the end of a shift will become intensive as your data set grows
- Finally, this does not take into consideration when you data has unmatched / paired values (i.e., two checkins without a checkout - vice-versa.)

For a Demo see this:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/558fb/22

Sample Output

```
| EMPID |                         CHECKIN |                        CHECKOUT | WORKED |
|-------|---------------------------------|---------------------------------|--------|
|     1 | November, 01 2012 21:45:00+0000 | November, 02 2012 06:05:00+0000 | 8.3333 |
|     1 | November, 02 2012 21:33:00+0000 | November, 03 2012 06:08:00+0000 | 8.5833 |
|     1 | November, 04 2012 11:49:00+0000 | November, 04 2012 21:39:00+0000 | 9.8333 |
|     1 | November, 05 2012 14:25:00+0000 | November, 05 2012 20:07:00+0000 |    5.7 |
```

SQL Code:

```
SELECT TimeIn.empID, TimeIn.BetterDate AS CheckIn, TimeOut.BetterDate AS CheckOut
, (TO_SECONDS(TimeOut.BetterDate) - TO_SECONDS(TimeIn.BetterDate))/(60*60) AS Worked
FROM (
SELECT empID, Type, Date, RecTime, DATE_ADD(Date, Interval RecTime HOUR_MINUTE) as BetterDate
FROM timedata) AS TimeIn
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT empID, Type, Date, RecTime, DATE_ADD(Date, Interval RecTime HOUR_MINUTE) as BetterDate
  FROM timedata) AS TimeOut
ON TimeIn.EmpID = TimeOut.EmpID
  AND TimeIn.BetterDate < TimeOut.BetterDate
  AND TimeOut.Type = '1-TIME OUT'
  AND NOT EXISTS 
    (SELECT *
    FROM TimeData
    WHERE TimeData.Type = '1-TIME OUT'
      AND DATE_ADD(Date, Interval RecTime HOUR_MINUTE) < TimeOut.BetterDate
      AND DATE_ADD(Date, Interval RecTime HOUR_MINUTE) > TimeIn.BetterDate)
WHERE TimeIn.Type = '1-TIME IN'
ORDER BY CheckIn, CheckOut
```